# Missing 'template' for ActionMailer, but only when running in test mode... Calling ActionMailer base class directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

This is a bit puzzling, when running this code in Production or Development, Rails does not complain about not finding the template, but when I run this into test mode, it is giving me an error saying it cannot find a "mailer" template...

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(:from => 'x@s.com', :to => "webmaster@az.com", :subject => 'some test', body: 'some body).deliver
```

I have even tried playing with the a format block, specifying { render text: 'x' } , for .html and .text, but no luck.

This is Rails 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the problem, since rails is all about conventions, it tries to guess the template path name and view name from the class name when the "BODY" passed on to the mailer is nil. So i.e. when using this method directly. I had to debug the rails framework to find this out:

I.e. on gems/actionmailer-4.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:

This method was the answer to the problem, as you can see if body eval to nil, then it goes the route of guessing path names, etc:

```
def collect_responses(headers) #:nodoc:
      responses = []

      if block_given?
        collector = ActionMailer::Collector.new(lookup_context) { render(action_name) }
        yield(collector)
        responses = collector.responses
      elsif headers[:body]
        responses << {
          body: headers.delete(:body),
          content_type: self.class.default[:content_type] || "text/plain"
        }
      else
        templates_path = headers.delete(:template_path) || self.class.mailer_name
        templates_name = headers.delete(:template_name) || action_name

        each_template(Array(templates_path), templates_name) do |template|
          self.formats = template.formats

          responses << {
            body: render(template: template),
            content_type: template.type.to_s
          }
        end
      end

      responses
    end
```